# SharePoint - Permissions to all sites

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can i add a service account to Share Point sites that has access to all the sites. One option is to manually add the account to sites one by one, but when there are over 500 sites, it is a painful process.

Is there a way/script to add account to all sites ?

## SharePoint online.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below powershell script to add the account as site admin to all sharepoint sites:

```
$Account="michael@tenant.com"
Connect-SPOService http://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com
$Sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL
Foreach ($Site in $Sites)
{
    Write-host "Adding Site Collection Admin for:"$Site.URL
    Set-SPOUser -site $Site -LoginName $Account -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $True
}
```

Updated:

Give the user read access to all sites:

```
$Sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL
Foreach ($Site in $Sites)
{
    $Groups=Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site $site
    foreach($Group in $Groups){
        if ($Group -like "*visitors"){
            Add-SPOUser -Site $site -LoginName $Accounr -Group $group
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But being a site admin it will have full access, is it possible to get read only access ?

Comment: Check my updated answer. Note: By default, SharePoint admin doesnot have permissions to all sites. He need to add himself as site admin to all sites.